# Internal Server Error when Attempting to Run Quickstart Tutorial for flask_restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am attempting to run the tutorial from the [Flask RESTful documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) but am running into an error when running the Resourceful routing code. I have copied the code for it verbatim, but when I attempt to run the code, I run into the situation below:

`export FLASK_APP=api.py`
`flask run`
`curl http://localhost:5000/todo1 -d "data=Remember the milk" -X PUT`

And the return is:

`{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`

Does anyone have a suggestion for what's happening here? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/todo1` should that be `http://localhost:5000/todos/1` ? Is that a typo in the question or the source of the problem?

Comment: That is how the tutorial writes it out, but if you think it is the source of the problem, I can definitely try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `flask run` command, production mode is the default setting. If Flask encounters an error while running in production mode, it will automatically suppress any errors and only return a generic `{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`. However, for development this can be very annoying as it makes it difficult to determine the root cause of an error.

Flask has a built-in development mode that--among other things--will disable this. Since you are using the flask cli the easiest thing to do would be to set an environment variable.

```sh
# Mac/Linux
$ export FLASK_ENV=development

# Windows
$ set FLASK_ENV=development

# The same command is used to undo this on both platforms
$ unset FLASK_ENV
```

This won't automatically fix the bug you're experiencing, but what it will do is allow you to see *why* you are encountering the error, which is usually more important anyway.

You can read more about the other available options for development mode [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#environments)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I ended up just trying to approach it using a different tutorial. Using the developer environment was enlightening, but I think it's just that the tutorial is either outdated, or missing some content.